# Triple Summation Of Product Of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

$ \sum\sum\sum\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k}
 $
Also it is given $0\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq n$.
I can not think of the solution. 
I can understand the question if it was $ \sum\sum\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}
$ and $0\leq i\leq j\leq n$.
Please provide a detailed solution if possible.

Comment: Yeah, show us what happens for the double sum & why things are more difficult for a triple sum.

Comment: $ \left ( \binom{n}{0} +\binom{n}{1}+.......+\binom{n}{n}\right )^{2}=\sum \binom{n}{r}^{2}+2\sum \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} $